# Why won't the message be sent to the channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi so I'm new to creating bots with Discord.py. I've gotten along pretty well using the docs although am now stuck.

Here's all the code from `commands.py`.

```
# All commands
cmds = {
    # The 'cmd' variable I'm using in the second code block
    "ping": {
        "name": "Ping",
        "description": "Ping pong",
        "usage_str": "ping",
        "rank_needed": 0,
        "execute": None
    }
}

# Define the function
def ping(client, message, channel, args):
    print("SENDING MESSAGE!")
    client.send_message(channel, "Pong!")

# Set the execute index in the dictionary to equal the function
cmds["ping"]["execute"] = ping
```

Here's the code from `main.py` that is calling the ping function.

```
cmd["execute"](client, message, channel, content)
```

When I attempt to execute the function I no message is sent into the channel although 'SENDING MESSAGE' is printed into the console. Why is this? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `await` the `send_message` coroutine, which means that `ping` itself must be a coroutine, and executed from inside an event loop.  I would recommend using the `discord.ext.commands` extension:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx, channel: discord.Channel, *, message):
    print("SENDING MESSAGE!")
    await bot.send_message(channel, message)

bot.run("token")
```

Comment: I allow servers to set custom prefixes and I'd like to handle my commands a custom way. Is there any other way I can keep my commands in a separate file and overcome this issue?

Comment: @mccrafter1212 Yes, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/leovoel/46cd89ed6a8f41fd09c5).  Unfortunately cogs are very poorly documented, but they're not that complicated.